# How to compile scss built with Webapp?

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

With Yeomam I choose Webapp project with bootstrap and scss.
In the html file it includes reference to main.css.
To run it I need to run grunt serve which creates main.css file from main.scss.
If I run directly the files from browser I will miss main.css because it has not been created from scss.
 How can I create it in order to run from browser without grunt?

Answer (score 0):

Another option to compile scss, programs like prepros or codekit, I use it daily in my work

prepros free:

https://prepros.io/

codekit:

https://incident57.com/codekit/

Comment: But I have received a project created by yeoman. is there an option to compile the  scss files provided by yeoman in the gruntfile.js?